# Entity Framework: Transform names of entities with table of aliases

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have entities Task and TaskAlias:

```
public class Task {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TaskAlias {
  public string SourceName { get; set; }
  public string TargetName { get; set; }
}
```

I have Web API method that returns set of Task. For result I need to replace name of Task if table TaskAlias contains alias for the name. How to solve this problem in an optimal way?

Comment: Dont read from your domain model... no mapping ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (taskCollection as task) {
    taskAlias = taskAliasRepository.findByTask(task);
    if (taskAlias) {
        task.setName(taskAlias.getTargetName);
        taskRepository.save(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I found more elegant solution using AutoMapper and custom value resolver (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).